# Postgresql stored procedure temporary table variable is not a known variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I've been doing research and trying things out a bunch of different ways, but with no success. I want to create a temporary table and then as I'm doing some searches, fill it up with stuff. I was able to do this with SQL Server by just declaring a table inside the procedure, but with Postgresql I've read I need to create a temporary table specifically.

My strategy started out with just

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE myTempTable
( 
    propOne bigint, 
    propTwo smallint, 
    createdAtUtc timestamp(6)
);
```

I even moved it to right after the "BEGIN". Down the file I get this error:

> ERROR:  "myTempTable" is not a known variable
> LINE 77:   SELECT * INTO myTempTable from myResult;

Next, I tried to create the temp table when I'm ready to fill it...

```
WITH some_updated_records AS 
(
    UPDATE dbTable
    SET tablePropertyStatus = 3
    WHERE tablePropertyDate < storedProcedurePropertyDate
    RETURNING *
)
CREATE TEMP TABLE myTempTable as 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM some_updated_records
);
```

I still get the same basic error above, but zero errors until it encounters the `myTempTable` variable.

I'm definitely not a SQL genius (perhaps, eventually, with your help), so there might be some other things I'm doing wrong. My whole task is to convert a SQL Server stored procedure to Postgresql.

What could I being doing wrong to make that temporary table variable un-declared? Is there a special way I need to declare it ahead of time? Am I making a mistake about how to create or declare a temporary table.

Another strategy could be to just keep saving records into a collection of types, forget the "temp table." Is there a way to do this in plpgsql?

### UPDATE w/Examples

This version doesn't work. It stops at the create table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MyTestProcedure(
    p_Endpoint Varchar(256),
    p_ContentType Varchar(200),
    MaxInProcess int = NULL)

LANGUAGE plpgsql

AS $body$

DECLARE
v_UtcNow timestamp(6);
v_ExpiredProcessing timestamp(6);

BEGIN
    SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP into v_UtcNow at time zone 'utc';

    WITH first_updated AS (UPDATE MyTable
        SET Status = 1
        WHERE UpdatedAtUtc < v_UtcNow
        RETURNING Id, Status, UpdatedAtUtc)
        
    CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS statustable AS (SELECT Id, Status, UpdatedAtUtc FROM first_updated)

    WITH m_result AS (UPDATE MyTable
    SET Status = 3,
    WHERE ExpirationDateTimeUtc < v_UtcNow
    RETURNING Id, Status, UpdatedAtUtc)
    
    INSERT INTO statustable from m_result;
            
    DROP TABLE statustable;
    
END;
$body$
```

This errors out at the table creation.

```
INE 22:  CREATE TEMP TABLE statustable as...
```

The other example would be something similar to creating the table first and then inserting into it. That's probably where I messed up. Working solution will be added in a minute, if someone doesn't add it in first.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and show us the complete code of the procedure. More often than not, you don't need a temp table to begin with when using Postgres

Comment: This is company code. I'll give it a try , but it will take a while. I come up with a more slimmed down version with the problem. Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: If you want to return something, you should be using a function not a procedure anyway.

Comment: The return for the procedure is void. I'm using the temporary table to perform some work at the end.

Comment: SQL Server [temporary tables as variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-declaring-a-variable-of-type-table) do not exist in plpgsql.

Comment: Insert into your temp table instead of selecting into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're debugging, things can get a little crazy. What happens often, I find, is I try one good solution, but I don't know how to implement it quite right, so the following works. I think I was forgetting the select in the INSERT INTO's.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MyTestProcedure(
    p_Endpoint Varchar(256),
    p_ContentType Varchar(200),
    MaxInProcess int = NULL)

LANGUAGE plpgsql

AS $body$

DECLARE
v_UtcNow timestamp(6);
v_ExpiredProcessing timestamp(6);

BEGIN
    SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP into v_UtcNow at time zone 'utc';

    CREATE TEMP TABLE status_table(  
        Id bigint,
        Status smallint,
        CreatedAtUtc timestamp(6));

    WITH first_updated AS (UPDATE MyTable
        SET Status = 1
        WHERE UpdatedAtUtc < v_UtcNow
        RETURNING Id, Status, UpdatedAtUtc)

    INSERT INTO status_table
        SELECT Id, Status, UpdatedAtUtc 
        FROM first_updated;

    WITH m_result AS (UPDATE MyTable
        SET Status = 3
        WHERE ExpirationDateTimeUtc < v_UtcNow
        RETURNING Id, Status, UpdatedAtUtc)
    
    INSERT INTO status_table
        select Id, Status, UpdatedAtUtc 
        from m_result;
            
    DROP TABLE status_table;
    
END;
$body$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE, but put the CTE within the parentheses for the table creation.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myTempTable AS (
  WITH cte_updated_records AS (
    UPDATE dbTable
    SET tablePropertyStatus = 3
    WHERE tablePropertyDate < storedProcedurePropertyDate
    RETURNING *
  )
  SELECT * FROM cte_updated_records
);
```

Comment: This is pretty neat. I'm going to try this one way or another.

Comment: You wouldn't expect it if you're coming from Sql Server, where the WITH has to be outside.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT1
Please refer the Tip section:

> Tip Note that this interpretation of SELECT with INTO is quite
> different from PostgreSQL's regular SELECT INTO command, wherein the
> INTO target is a newly created table. If you want to create a table
> from a SELECT result inside a PL/pgSQL function, use the syntax CREATE
> TABLE ... AS SELECT.

based on this then you can do

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE  statustable AS (here is your query clause)
```

Maybe you can do update later.
Another Point is as per manual, seems you cannot do CREATE Table by using CTE.

> Each auxiliary statement in a WITH clause can be a SELECT, INSERT,
> UPDATE, or DELETE; and the WITH clause itself is attached to a primary
> statement that can also be a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html

LukStorms's answer is pretty neat. But serval steps maybe more readable?

Comment: Thanks so much! ...Yeah, there's ongoing battle between readability and expediency, but when it comes to readability and making things work... That's when the suffering begins. Haha.